# WooCommerce: Localise some text button in storefront theme

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, translation, storefront

I am making Wordpress/WooCommerce webiste, and I am using **"Storefront"** as theme, but now I have problem because I am not making website in English, so now I want to change buttons text, on example "View Basket", "Checkout" and "Add to Basket".

But I don't know where can I change it in code. Or what I need to do to change it?

Comment: @LoicTheAztec I just want to correct the text on the button, that is all.

Answer (score 1):

You can install Storefront in a language of your choice. You might want to follow this guide https://docs.woothemes.com/document/installing-storefront-in-your-language/

There you will also find the link to create a custom **WooCommerce Localization**

You will need to decide what fits your needs.

Custom translations can basically be done by putting translation files into

```
wp-content/languages/themes/
```

For Storefront name the file

```
storefront-it_IT.mo
```

You will find more information on the refered link

Answer (score 0):

Ok what is properly answer here, and most easiest solution: You should download translated files for your language, probably Wordpress community from your country did it already. So zipped files you should unzip and insert into 
wp-content/languages/themes and wp-content/languages/plugins. You should have 2 files with .po and .mo extensions. After that simply go in your dashboard->settings->Site language: "Your language". 
And that should be it.
https://docs.woothemes.com/document/installing-storefront-in-your-language/